# Update components based on props

Tags: reactjs

I have one reusable component which receives prop `series`. That prop contains the `data` object. Depends on `data.length` I need to update the component. In case one, `data.lenght` is 20, and in case two `data.length` is 6. But when I try to achieve this, component renders only the case where `data.length` is 20, and when I hit refresh it takes the second case where `data.length` is 6. I have tried using `useEffect()` hook but it doesn't work. Apparently I'm missing something. Here is what I've tried so far

```
const ReusableComponent = ({series}) => {
     const [propSeries, setSeries] = useState(series.data.length);
     useEffect(() => {
        if(propSeries > 6) {
          // do something
        }
     }, [propSeries])
}
```

Here is the example of my problem: [example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wueUpjR5AI5hHwoi58sqJdNjkoTdXbox/view).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `useState` only gets initialized on the first render. So `propSeries` will never update unless you do it explicitly with `setSeries`. Just like in class components: only use state if it is a value that will change over time, and is not a direct copy of props. Otherwise, just use the prop directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you set your props into your state? You could just something like this:

```
const ReusableComponent = ({series}) => {
     useEffect(() => {
        if(series.data.length > 6) {
          // do something
        }
     }, [series])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect` hook will execute when the component loads set the Series inside the `useEffect` hook before checking for the length.this way you could implement `componentWillReceiveProps` functionality using hooks

```
 const [propSeries, setSeries] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setSeries(series.data.length);
    if (propSeries > 6) {
      alert("Prop Series is Greatar than 6");
    }
  }, [series, propSeries]);
```

i created a working example, CodeSadbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-bash-tg72i?file=/src/ReusableComponent.js:133-356)

Hope this helps

Comment: @Milos i think your issue may lay somewhere else because the approach is perfectly fine even in your question or in `maten`s answer